# Titan Key with given name does not exist

Tags: titan

I create two indexes but when I want to invoke `vertex.setProperties()`, my program prompts with  "given name does not exist.".  Below is my code:

```
 initDB

 public void tstInitHBase() {
        Configuration conf = new BaseConfiguration();

        conf.setProperty("storage.backend", "hbase");
        conf.setProperty("storage.hostname", "192.168.22.209");
        conf.setProperty("storage.port", "2181");
        conf.setProperty("storage.tablename", "social_map");

        conf.setProperty("cache.db-cache", "true");
        conf.setProperty("cache.db-cache-clean-wait", "20");
        conf.setProperty("cache.db-cache-time", "180000");
        conf.setProperty("cache.db-cache-size", "0.5");

        GraphDatabaseConfiguration graphconfig = new GraphDatabaseConfiguration(conf);
        try {
            graphconfig.getBackend().clearStorage();
        } catch (StorageException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Techvalley:ERROR 清空数据库失败");
        }


        TitanGraph graph = TitanFactory.open(conf);
        graph.makeKey("PKID").dataType(String.class).indexed(Vertex.class).unique(UniquenessConsistency.LOCK).make();
        graph.makeKey("CN_NAME").dataType(String.class).indexed(Vertex.class).make();
        graph.makeKey("EDGE_PEERS_WEIGHT").dataType(Long.class).indexed(Edge.class).make();
        graph.commit();
    }
```

Insert Data with pig

```
//objList structure is like (uuid,cn_name,gender,..)
vertex = tx.getVertex(DataType.toString(objList.get(0)));

            if (vertex == null) {
                logger.info("create node");
                vertex = tx.addVertex(DataType.toString(objList.get(0)));
                vertex.setProperty(flied[0], DataType.toString(objList.get(0)));
            } 

            /**
             * 
             * */
            for (int i = 1; i < flied.length; i++) {
                switch (DataType.findType(objList.get(i))) {
                case DataType.NULL:
                    logger.info("cache" + flied[i] + " " + DataType.toString(objList.get(i)));
                    ElementHelper.setProperties(vertex, flied[i],DataType.toString(objList.get(i)));
                    break;
                case DataType.CHARARRAY:
                    logger.info("cache" + flied[i] + " " + DataType.toString( objList.get(i)));
                    ElementHelper.setProperties(vertex, flied[i],DataType.toString(objList.get(i)));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
```

When I execute `ElementHelper.setProperties(vertex,flied[i],DataType.toString(objList.get(i)));` my program always returns 'Key with given name does not exist'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you insert data without pig?  For example, will it work if you insert from the Titan Console?

Answer (score 0):

Find out the offending property key by wrapping ElementHelper.setProperties in try/catch and logging/printing the property key name. Then add it to the graph.makeKey set.